# What is the purpose of ~' or '~ in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, macros

I am learning about Clojure macros, and the code examples will sometimes have the constructs `'~symbol` or alternately `~'symbol`. I know that `(quote` and `'` prevent a form from being evaluated, and that the backquote additionally adds namespace qualification, and that ~ causes a quoted form to be evaluated. My question is: why is it useful to stop then start evaluation? I also assume that `~'symbol` and `'~symbol` are different, but how so?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`~'symbol` is used to produce an *unqualified* symbol. Clojure's macros capture namespace by default, so a symbol in a macro would normally be resolved to `(your-namespace/symbol)`. The unquote-quote idiom directly results in the simple, unqualified symbol name - `(symbol)` - by evaluating to a quoted symbol. From The Joy Of Clojure:

```
(defmacro awhen [expr & body]
  `(let [~'it ~expr] ; refer to the expression as "it" inside the body
    (when ~'it
      (do ~@body))))

(awhen [:a :b :c] (second it)) ; :b
```

`'~symbol` is likely used to insert a name in the macro or something similar. Here, `symbol` will be bound to a value - `let [symbol 'my-symbol]`. This value is then inserted into the code the macro produces by evaluating `symbol`.

```
(defmacro def-symbol-print [sym]
  `(defn ~(symbol (str "print-" sym)) []
    (println '~sym))) ; print the symbol name passed to the macro

(def-symbol-print foo)
(print-foo) ; foo
```

Comment: there's still a point which remains unclear to me: `(unquote (quote user/foo))` results in `foo` instead of `user/foo`, when and how does it happen that the namespace gets stripped away? How is it consistent with the "normal" behavior of `unquote` which evaluates the following form?

Comment: The first example is not working. It should be `\`(let [~'it ~expr] ...`

Comment: @skuro Step by step: 1. \`foo captures the namespace and so evaluates to user/foo. 2. \`'foo namespace is still captured, but the result is a call to quote: (quote user/foo) 3. \`~'foo still captured, than wrapped in quote and finally the quote is evaluated, which returns just foo. Same way '+ evaluates to +.

Answer (score 6):

`~` is a reader macro for the `unquote` function. within a quoted list it causes a symbol to be evaluated rather then used as a literal symbol

```
user> (def unquoted 4)
user>`(this is an ~unquoted list)
(user/this user/is user/an 4 clojure.core/list)
user>
```

everything except the symbol unquoted was used just as a symbol where unquoted was resolved to its value of 4. this is **most often used in writing macros.** The repl also prints the namespace (user) infront of the names when it is printing the resulting list.

many macros, are basically just templates designed to do a bunch of slight variations on something that can't be done in a function. In this contrived example a template macro defines a function by producing a call to def. syntax-quote with unquoting makes this much easier to read:

```
user> (defmacro def-map-reducer [name mapper reducer] 
         `(defn ~name [& args#] 
              (reduce ~reducer (map ~mapper args#))))

#'user/def-map-reducer
user> (def-map-reducer add-incs inc +)
#'user/add-incs
user> (add-incs 1 2 3 4 5)
20
```

compared to:

```
user> (defmacro def-map-reducer [name mapper reducer] 
          (let [args-name (gensym)] 
              (list `defn name [`& args-name] 
                   (list `reduce reducer (list `map mapper args-name)))))

#'user/def-map-reducer
user> (def-map-reducer add-decs dec +)
#'user/add-decs
user> (add-decs 1 2 3 4 5)
10
user>
```

in the second example I also don't use the auto-gensyms feature because I'm not in a syntax-quote

Comment: So I do know why I would want to use ~ in front of a symbol in a list that I had previously quoted, my question is specifically why I would use ~' or '~ right next to each other.

Comment: hopefully this example will show the motivation better, thanks for the feedback :)