# How clojure macro parses special symbol?

Tags: clojure, macros, syntax-rules

When I re-implement a macro written in Scheme with Clojure, I get into a trouble.
The macro tries to load pairs of testing data into a `all-tests` var for later use.

Because the arguments for the macro is variable-length and contains special undefined symbol, i.e. `=>`, I simply don't know how to parse it like what Scheme syntax-rules does.

Scheme Version:

```
(define all-tests '())

;;; load tests into all-tests
(define-syntax add-tests-with-string-output
  (syntax-rules (=>)
    [(_ test-name [expr => output-string] ...)
     (set! all-tests
        (cons 
           '(test-name [expr string  output-string] ...)
            all-tests))]))

(add-tests-with-string-output "integers"      
  [0  => "0\n"]                    
  [1  => "1\n"]                    
  [-1 => "-1\n"]                   
  [10  => "10\n"]                    
  [-10 => "-10\n"]                   
  [2736 => "2736\n"]               
  [-2736 => "-2736\n"]             
  [536870911 => "536870911\n"]     
  [-536870912 => "-536870912\n"]   
)
```

My current unsuccessful Clojure Version:

```
(def all-tests (atom '()))

(defmacro add-tests-with-string-output
  [test-name & body]
  `(loop [bds# (list body)]
    (when-not (empty? bds#)
      (println (first bds#))
      (recur (rest bds#)))))
```

Ps: I am using `println` to test my code right now. When it works, I will try to do the parsing and loading work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first macro forms a loop and the second one a `doseq` (so is simpler). Both should behave the same. Also I find it a good idea to extract as much logic out of macros into auxiliary functions. Functions are easier to debug, test and write. If the macro were a bit more complicated I might have left even less logic in it.

```
(def all-tests (atom '()))

(defn add-test [test-name expr output-string]
  (swap! all-tests #(cons (list test-name [expr output-string]) %)))

(defmacro add-tests-with-string-output
  [test-name & body]
  ;`(loop [bds# '(~@body)]
  `(loop [bds# '~body] ; edit
    (when-not (empty? bds#)
      (let [bd# (first bds#)
            expr# (first bd#)
            output-string# (last bd#)]
        (add-test ~test-name expr# output-string#)
        (recur (rest bds#))
        ))))

(defmacro add-tests-with-string-output2
  [test-name & body]
  ;`(doseq [bd# '(~@body)]
  `(doseq [bd# '~body] ; edit
    (let [expr# (first bd#)
          output-string# (last bd#)]
      (add-test ~test-name expr# output-string#))))

user=> (add-tests-with-string-output "test1" [0  => "0\n"] [1  => "1\n"])
nil
user=> (add-tests-with-string-output2 "test2" [0  => "0\n"] [1  => "1\n"])
nil
user=> @all-tests
(("test2" [1 "1\n"]) ("test2" [0 "0\n"]) ("test1" [1 "1\n"]) ("test1" [0 "0\n"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

After trials and errors, finally I figure out how to solve it.

First use **Destructuring** to tackle the arguments of variable-length;
later do not use **Syntax-Quoting**, i.e. backquote `, inside the macro, because if so, once you need to unquote `~` the argument, i.e. `body`, you will get error msg like this due to the special symbol `=>`:

> CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve
>   symbol: => in this context

Below is my solution.
If you get better one, or you know the reason why Syntax-Quote and Unquote go wrong, please let me know.

```
;;; load tests into all-tests
(def all-tests (atom '()))
(defmacro add-tests-with-string-output
  [test-name & body]
  (loop [bds body, tests '()]
    (if (empty? bds)
      (do 
        (swap! all-tests #(cons (cons test-name tests) %))
        nil)
      (let [pair (first bds),
            input (first pair)
            output (last pair)]
        (recur (rest bds) (cons (list input ''string output) tests))))))
```

Comment: `defmacro` is similar to `defn` in that it defines a function, but it runs at compile time (to best of my understanding) and leaves the return value as replacement for the `defmacro` call. So a problem is that the macro you defined runs `swap!` at compile time (which still works in repl). What you want to do is to have `defmacro` return the actual code that you want to run at runtime. In this case the macro simply returns `nil`, so you'll probably have no behaviour at runtime.

Comment: You were getting the `Unable to resolve symbol` error because your macro was prematurely evaluating your input code/data. You probably did something like `\`~args` while destructuring. You can simply use a quote to fix that: `\`'~args`. That would expand to `'(arg1 arg2 arg3)` (notice the quote).

Comment: @DominykasMostauskis I found the post below about the syntax ``'~args`` and still quite confused, but your explaination serves me even better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959107/what-is-the-purpose-of-or-in-clojure

Comment: `'~` in expression `(defmacro m [& args] \`'~args)` does this: unquote (`~`) replaces `args` in the macro body with the `args` value from the parameter destructuring. Given `(m 1 2 3)` that value would be `(1 2 3)`. Here lies the catch, if you just leave it like that, this is not a list but a function call and you would get an error. So enter the quote (`'`); with it (`'~args`) the expression `(m 1 2 3)` is expanded to `'(1 2 3)` which is a list of symbols. Same goes for something like `[1 => "1\n"]`: you have to quote it otherwise your "sugar" symbol will be interpreted as a var.